# execute multiple activities in parallel PAF?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

How can I execute multiple activities in parallel PAF? Is it possible to execute multiple activities in "parallel" PAF?

Answer (score 0):

Parallel execution of multiple activities is not possible in PAF.

Comment: Hi, weclome to SO, Could you give the officila link (doc) where this point is explain please.